# How to use new API elements like Switch so, that the app is compatible with older Android version?

Tags: android

I want to use new UI elements like Switch for new Android devices, and by older devices I would use something else like Button.

I have created to layouts

```
~/res/
   layout/main.xml
   layout-v14/main.xml
```

that has different elements like Button in `layout/main.xml` and Switch in `layout-v14/main.xml`

But how can I add different elements in the Activity, without to get Exception like

```
Could not find class 'android.widget.Switch' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to inspect the device's API level at runtime. That way, you can add conditional code in your Java classes that will vary its behavior based on the user's API level, like so:

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ) {
  // Some code that requires API level 14+
} else {
  // Code that will run on lower API levels instead
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Switch` you can try the [`SwitchCompat`](https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary) library, to make it backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You usually include the Support Library in your project dependencies for that purpose.
(http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

You can then use new objects (like Fragments for example) with older devices.

Unfortunately, `Switch` is not among them...